# Change the <a> element class in react-bootstrap NavItem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to work with `react-bootstrap` and change the `NavItem` inner `<a>` element's class. I tried using `className` but it didn't affect it.

I want to change the colour of the `hover` action. How can I do it?

```
<Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">1</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">2</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#" className="my-class">3</NavItem>
      </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

css:

```
.xnavbar-tab a {
  color: #F89800;
}
```

Comment: Pls add a little more code and the behaviour as well. How are you adding/removing classes on hover?

Comment: I add the `:hover` action in the css file, but even just changing the color doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

to change the anchor element that is created with bootstrap-react (for example in bootstrap-react tabs) you just need to assign a class to the parent and let it know that its anchor children should have them applied like so

```
.your-class > a
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that's possible, looking at the source.

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/NavItem.js

Look at linkProps object. It does not contain className. Why is this important? Because, the anchor is taking the linkProps object as its properties. So each key-value pair within linkProps ends up becoming a prop to the anchor. If className is not present within linkProps, which is the case here, it means that there is no way that you can pass it from outside NavItem.

```
 <SafeAnchor {...linkProps} aria-controls={ariaControls}>
      { children }
    </SafeAnchor>
```

More info : 
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/SafeAnchor.js

**Solution**:

Manage the css of the anchor within the NavItem, based on the class of the NavItem.

```
 .nav-item.my-nav-item-class a{
    color : requiredcolor;
  }
```

Comment: I have encountered this issue for quite few times, this is a bit limiting isn't it? Say I wanna change a few fonts and classes...

Comment: Actually no, I dont see a reason to add a class to the anchor element, because you do have the ability to add a class to the parent and are definitely able to change styles based on it.

Comment: In the current context, you have a NavItem component and I think the component has implemented a decent level of abstraction and at the same time has exposed the props needed to change its behavior.

Comment: Please see my edited question. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSX you can do it like this:

```
const css = `
        .hover-list a:hover {
        color: #F89800;
    }
`

<div className="hover-list">
    <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">1</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">2</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#" className="my-class">3</NavItem>
          </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</div>
```