# React Tsx with React Bootstrap - Inline CSS for Active NavItem

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I would like to change the background color for the `active` NavItem element to green using inline CSS. I'm using TypeScript 2.2, React, React Bootstrap, React Router Dom and React Router Bootstrap. Is this possible or do I need to create a CSS class?

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation

Current code:

```
const tabStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}

return (
    <main>
        <div>
            <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey="1">
                <LinkContainer to="/about">
                    <NavItem eventKey="1">Om</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/facts">
                    <NavItem eventKey="2">Fakta</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
        </div>
    </main>
);
```

Comment: In order to change the css properties of Nav you need to write custom css for the class `nav`. Go through a normal bootstrap class reference and then add your custom styles and import them. That should work, Nav doesn't provide option to use custom style attribute and hence I don't think you can do that through inline css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the props as far as I can see and besides that props are immutable. You might want to look into `state` and use that as the `backGroundColor` but for inline styling it could look like this

```
 <div style={{color: condition ? "red": "green"}}> </div>
```

EDIT: Seems like there is no styling intended for the `NavItem`. See [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2070). You have to use css for that e.g. [Change the <a> element class in react-bootstrap NavItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090020/change-the-a-element-class-in-react-bootstrap-navitem)

Comment: NavItem does not have a style property. If I try to wrap it in a  `span` or  `div` the NavItem appears outside the navbar.

Comment: @Ogglas Seems like you have to use CSS. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah seems like the simplest choice

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like this, not the prettiest solution but works fine.

```
const css = `
    .route-list .nav-tabs>li.active>a {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
`

<main>
    <div className="route-list">
        <style>{css}</style>
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey="1">
            <LinkContainer to="/about">
                <NavItem eventKey="1">Om</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/facts">
                <NavItem eventKey="2">Fakta</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
    </div>
</main>
```